# Wrong encoding using liquibase and docker postgis/postgis

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I have a very strange behaviors with my sprintboot project using a docker postgresql db postgis/postgis.

I create the docker container with the db with this docker file:

```
version: '3'
    services:
      project-postgresql:
        image: postgis/postgis:13-master
        volumes:
          - ./postgres-initdb/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=xxx
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxx
        ports:
          - 9432:5432
```

the database is create in UTF8:

```
project-postgresql_1  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
project-postgresql_1  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
project-postgresql_1  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
```

When I start my springboot project, liquibase changelogs are played with some inserts into the database but the encoding seems wrong and all accent are replaced by special char.

What I checked:

- the encoding of the changelog files in another editor than intellij and encoding is correctly set to utf8.
- in the db console, I tried to ran a SHOW SERVER_ENCODING and it is UTF8
- I tried to delete a row with the wrong encoding and run a copy past insert from the changelog in the console and the encoding is correct
- Trying to persist some data from the application with accents and it works.
- Trying to run a liquibase:update -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 before start the application, same encoding problem.
- I looked the target backend\target\classes\db\ the encoding of the changelogs and they are correct.
- Try to delete the docker container, the image and restart from scratch.

We are 3 dev on the same project and the problem is only on my dev machine, all my others projects using the same stack work on the same machine.

additional informations:

```
<liquibase.version>4.3.5</liquibase.version>
<liquibase-hibernate5.version>4.3.5</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
<testcontainers.version>1.15.3</testcontainers.version>
<hibernate-types.version>2.10.2</hibernate-types.version>
```

Do you maybe know a way to show an output of the insert statements played by liquibase at the startup? or maybe another idea to fix that?

**UPDATE**

I tried to change the liquibase version from 4.3.5 to an older version (3.8.7) and it works. Il also tried to delete liquibase from my .m2 folder and import again the version 4.3.5 and same problem again.

Thanks,
Ersch

Answer (score 0):

We have seen this issue happen, and possible solution for this would be setting `JAVA_OPTS` parameter. This solution has worked for those using liquibase CLI.

```
For Windows:
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 && liquibase update

For Linux:
JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 liquibase update
```